# My coding isn't letting me play again instead it just loops back around

Tags: python

So basically I have this program that is a quiz and at the end, I want to make the user be able to say if they want to play again and if they say yes it takes them back up to the top and starts again but instead what my coding has been doing is skipping the question of do you want to play again and making them answer the first two questions at the top of my coding and then afterwards asking them if they want to play again but that cycle of questions just loops around until I say no

this is the first function and the main statement part of my coding I couldn't put in the entire thing cause it is too long

```
def main():
 atawhai, student_id = details()
 quiz_type = quiz()
 complete_quiz(quiz_type)
 if quiz_type == QUIZ_CHOICE[0]:
  correct_answers = g_responses()
 else:
  correct_answers = r_responses()
 display(atawhai, student_id, correct_answers)
 play_again = "Y"
 while play_again == "Y":
  atawhai, student_id = details()
  play_again = input("Do you want to retake the quiz Y or N")

main()
```

Comment: What is detail function

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap your code in a while loop and keep asking the user, every time game ends.
For example you can keep your game logic in a function called play and in your main you set a default value for the play again flag to y or Y and execute your code in a while loop and at the end of the loop ask the user if wants to play again and loop will execute one more time and so on ...
Check the below code

```
def play():
    # you game logic goes here ...
    print("my game code is here")


def main():
    play_again = "y"
    while play_again == "y" or play_again == "Y":
        play()
        play_again = input("Do you want to play again (y,n)?")
    print("Bye!")
```

Thanks